# Why are "smoke tests" called "smoke tests"?

Tags: smoke-testing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a smoke testing and what will it do for me?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/745192/what-is-a-smoke-testing-and-what-will-it-do-for-me)

Why are "smoke tests" called "smoke tests"?  I don't get this at all.  What does smoke have to do with it?

Comment: Turn it on and see if it starts smoking.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

See also answer to [What is a smoke testing and what will it do for me?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/745192/what-is-a-smoke-testing-and-what-will-it-do-for-me/745279#745279):

> The term originates in hardware repair
>   and has been applied to software. It's
>   intended to be a quick test to see if
>   the application "catches on fire" when
>   run for the first time. As stated
>   above it's just to make sure you don't
>   waste a bunch of folks time by setting
>   them loose on something that's
>   obviously broken.

Answer (score 13):

It comes from hardware. After you've assembled/soldered/wired everything together, you connect it to mains and turn it on.

- If you don't see or smell smoke, test is successful. :)
- If there is smoke, disconnect power immediately! (and figure out the problem before re-test...)

Answer (score 6):

Smoke testing originated in the hardware testing practice of turning on a new piece of hardware for the first time and considering it a success if it does not catch fire and smoke.