# What is the difference between smoke testing and sanity testing?

Tags: testing, manual-testing, smoke-testing

What is the difference between smoke testing and sanity testing? When do will perform smoke testing and when do will perform sanity testing?

Answer (score 38):

### Sanity testing

Sanity testing is the subset of regression testing and it is performed when we do not have enough time for doing testing.

Sanity testing is the surface level testing where QA engineer verifies that all the menus, functions, commands available in the product and project are working fine.

---

#### Example

For example, in a project there are 5 modules: *Login Page*, *Home Page*, *User's Details Page*, *New User Creation* and *Task Creation*.

Suppose we have a bug in the login page: the login page's username field accepts usernames which are shorter than 6 alphanumeric characters, and this is against the requirements, as in the requirements it is specified that the username should be at least 6 alphanumeric characters.

Now the bug is reported by the testing team to the developer team to fix it. After the developing team fixes the bug and passes the app to the testing team, the testing team also checks the other modules of the application in order to verify that the bug fix does not affect the functionality of the other modules. 
But keep one point always in mind: the testing team only checks the extreme functionality of the modules, it does not go deep to test the details because of the short time.

---

Sanity testing is performed after the build has cleared the smoke tests and has been accepted by QA team for further testing. Sanity testing checks the major functionality with finer details.

Sanity testing is performed when the development team needs to know quickly the state of the product after they have done changes in the code, or there is some controlled code changed in a feature to fix any critical issue, and stringent release time-frame does not allow complete regression testing.

---

### Smoke testing

Smoke Testing is performed after a software build to ascertain that the critical functionalities of the program are working fine. It is executed "before" any detailed functional or regression tests are executed on the software build.

The purpose is to reject a badly broken application, so that the QA team does not waste time installing and testing the software application.

In smoke testing, the test cases chosen cover the most important functionalities or components of the system. The objective is not to perform exhaustive testing, but to verify that the critical functionalities of the system are working fine.
For example, typical smoke tests would be:

> - verify that the application launches successfully,
> - Check that the GUI is responsive

Comment: With this definition of sanity check, the difference is not so clear. After researching, it looks like none are in depth tests, but Sanity checks focus on new functionalities. Both are executed before sending the build to QA. https://www.guru99.com/smoke-sanity-testing.html and http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/smoke-testing-and-sanity-testing-difference/

Comment: According to your definition “ that ALL the menus, functions, commands available” the sanity check can be quite a big work. Other answers/sources limit Sanity checks to new/ modified functionalities only.

Answer (score 20):

### Smoke testing

Smoke testing came from the hardware environment where testing should be done to check whether the development of a new piece of hardware causes no fire and smoke for the first time.

In the software environment, smoke testing is done to verify whether we can consider for further testing the functionality which is newly built.

### Sanity testing

A subset of regression test cases are executed after receiving a functionality or code with small or minor changes in the functionality or code, to check whether it resolved the issues or software bugs and no other software bug is introduced by the new changes.

---

### Difference between smoke testing and sanity testing

#### Smoke testing

- Smoke testing is used to test all areas of the application without going into too deep.
- A smoke test always use an automated test or a written set of tests. It is always scripted.
- Smoke testing is designed to include every part of the application in a not thorough or detailed way.
- Smoke testing always ensures whether the most crucial functions of a program are working, but not bothering with finer details.

#### Sanity testing

- Sanity testing is a narrow test that focuses on one or a few areas of functionality, but not thoroughly or in-depth.
- A sanity test is usually unscripted.
- Sanity testing is used to ensure that after a minor change a small part of the application is still working.
- Sanity testing is a cursory testing, which is performed to prove that the application is functioning according to the specifications. This level of testing is a subset of regression testing.

Hope these points help you to understand the difference between smoke testing and sanity testing.

---

#### References

- http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/smoke-testing-and-sanity-testing-difference/
- https://www.guru99.com/smoke-sanity-testing.html

Answer (score 5):

### Smoke and sanity testing

In general, smoke and sanity testing seems very similar to many tester who have just started, because in both we talk about *build*, we talk about *functionality* and we talk about the *rejection of builds*, if build's health is not good for the feasible testing.

After going through several projects, from start ups to product base company, I figured out the basic difference between smoke and sanity testing.

I am writing difference between smoke testing and sanity testing here to help you in answering at least one question that normally all testers get asked in interview.

#### Smoke testing

- Smoke testing is done to test the *health of builds*.
- It is also known as the shallow and wide testing, in that we normally include those test cases which can cover all the functionality of the product.
- We can say that it's the first step of testing and, after this, we normally do other kind of functional and system testing, including regression testing.
- It's normally done by a developer with the help of certain scripts or certain tools, but in some cases it can be performed by a tester too.
- It's valid for initial stage of a build confirmation. For example, suppose we have started the development of a certain product, and we are producing a build for the first time, then smoke testing becomes a necessity for the product.

#### Sanity testing

- It is sub-regression
- Sanity is done for those builds which have gone through many regression tests and a minor change in code has happened. In this case, we normally do the intensive testing of functionalities where this change has occurred or may have influenced.

  - Due to this, it is also known as "narrow" and "deep" testing
- It's performed by a tester
- It's done for mature builds, like those that are just going to hit production, and have gone through multiple regression processes.
- It can be removed from the testing process, if regression is already being performed.
- If any build doesn't pass the sanity tests, then it is thrown to developer back for the correction of the build.

Answer (score 4):

Try to understand both by this example.

---

Suppose if you're buying a car from showroom.

The first thing you will check the car contains are for example if it's four tires, a staring, headlight, or all other basic things. This is called **smoke testing**.

If you're checking how much mileage the car is giving or what is max speed, then this is known as **sanity testing**.

Answer (score 1):

**Smoke testing** is about checking if the requirements are satisfied or not.
Smoke testing is a *general health check up*.

**Sanity testing** is about checking if a particular module is completely working or not. Sanity testing is *specialized in particular health check up*.

Answer (score 1):

**Smoke tests** are tests which aim is to check if everything was build correctly. I mean here integration, connections. So you check from technically point of view if you can make wider tests. You have to execute some test cases and check if the results are positive.

**Sanity tests** in general have the same aim - check if we can make further test. But in sanity test you focus on business value so you execute some test cases but you check the logic.

In general people say smoke tests for both above because they are executed in the same time (sanity after smoke tests) and their aim is similar.

Answer (score -1):

#### Smoke testing

Suppose a new build of an app is ready from the development phase.

We check if we are able to open the app without a crash. We login to the app. We check if the user is redirected to the proper URL and that the environment is stable. If the main aim of the app is to provide a "purchase" functionality to the user, check if the user's ID is redirected to the buying page.

After the *smoke testing* we confirm the build is in a testable form and is ready to go through sanity testing.

#### Sanity testing

In this phase, we check the basic functionalities, like

1. login with valid credentials,
2. login with invalid credentials,
3. user's info are properly displayed after logging in,
4. making a purchase order with a certain user's id,
5. the "thank you" page is displayed after the purchase

Answer (score -1):

THERE IS NO DIFFERENCE BETWEEN smoke and sanity as per ISTQB.

sanity is synonym of smoke.

Check it here : https://glossary.istqb.org/en/search/sanity

Comment: Not sure who downvoted this, but this will simply mean that you fo not agree with ISTQB

Comment: If you are still not clear refer this: https://glossary.istqb.org/en/search/smoke%20test

Answer (score -3):

Smoke Testing:-

Smoke test is scripted, i.e you have either manual test cases or automated scripts for it.

Sanity Testing:-

Sanity tests are mostly non scripted.